# Code to download all Plotly graphs generated in a for loop as a pdf?

Tags: python, for-loop, pdf, graph, plotly

I am generating 7 graphs each for 500 institutions in Plotly. I am able to just download each graph as a png and then convert those into a pdf. But it is time-consuming, and I am sure there is an easier way that I cannot figure out. I would like to write a line of code that can produce all graphs listed below into one pdf if possible. My code is below:

```
count=0
for o in new_df['origin'].unique()[20:21]:
    origin_df=new_df.loc[new_df['origin']==o]
    graph1a()
    graph2()
    graph3a()
    graph4()
    graph5()
    graph6a()
    graph777()
```

Comment: what exactly do the functions `graph1a, ... graph777` do? do they return plotly figures or save plot figures somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in the plotly documentation about [creating pdf reports](https://plotly.com/python/v3/pdf-reports/#part-2--convert-the-html-to-pdf-with-xhtml2pdf).   Assuming that your functions `graph1a, ... graph777` all return plotly figures, you can do something like the following:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import base64

from IPython.display import display, HTML

width = 600
height = 600

template = (''
    '<img style="width: {width}; height: {height}" src="data:image/png;base64,{image}">'
    '{caption}'                              # Optional caption to include below the graph
    '<br>'
    '<hr>'
'')

# A collection of Plotly graphs
count=0
for n, o in enumerate(new_df['origin'].unique()[20:21]):
    origin_df=new_df.loc[new_df['origin']==o]
    figures = [
        graph1a(),
        graph2(),
        graph3a(),
        graph4(),
        graph5(),
        graph6a(),
        graph777(),
    ]

    # Generate their images using `py.image.get`
    images = [base64.b64encode(py.image.get(figure, width=width, height=height)).decode('utf-8') for figure in figures]

    report_html = ''
    for image in images:
        _ = template
        _ = _.format(image=image, caption='', width=width, height=height)
        report_html += _

    display(HTML(report_html))
    convert_html_to_pdf(report_html, f'report-{n}.pdf')
```